# In-place transpose of a 2-d vector passed by reference

Tags: c++, matrix, transpose

I am trying to compute the transpose of a matrix. Now, I have passed the matrix as a 2-d vector, and since I want the function to calculate the transpose in-place, I passed the 2-d vector by reference. But it seems to take no effect.

I tried to use `std::swap(mat[i][j], mat[j][i])`, it had no effect. Again, I tried to manually swap the integers (using a third variable), still no effect.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

#define N 5

void inPlaceTranspose(std::vector<std::vector<int> > &mat) {
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            int temp = mat[i][j];
            mat[i][j] = mat[j][i];
            mat[j][i] = temp;
            //std::swap(mat[i][j], mat[j][i]);
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Transpose:\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            std::cout << mat[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > mat(N, std::vector<int>(N));
    mat = {
        {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
        {7, 8, 9, 10, 11},
        {13, 14, 15, 16, 17},
        {19, 20, 21, 22, 23},
        {25, 26, 27, 28, 29},
    };
    std::cout << "Original Matrix:\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            std::cout << mat[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    inPlaceTranspose(mat);
    return 0;
}
```

The `Original Matrix` and `Transpose` are coming out to be same.

Comment: You are transposing every location twice.  You just want to do a triangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not in the way you pass the matrix, or in the way you do the swap. The problem is in your logic here:

```
for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
```

which results in swapping the elements *twice*, thus cancelling out your attempt to transpose the matrix.

Try looping until `i`, instead of `N`, like this:

```
for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
```

instead.